# Inverting path in string with escaped spaces

Tags: python, windows, path, escaping

I need to pass a subtitle path to VLC, it only takes native paths (backslashes on Windows, forward slashes on Unix) and needs space escaping.

Let's say I have a Qt native path with a space in it.

`C:/Users/Thinkpad/Downloads/test file.srt`

How do I convert it into this:

`C:\\Users\\Thinkpad\\Downloads\\test\ file.srt`

Comment: Just put double quotes around it. Save yourself the bother.

Comment: VLC does not support that.

Comment: OK, sorry. What context?

Comment: I need to pass a string to VLC's `--sub-path=FILE` parameter. It must be a native path (`"\"` on WIndows) and spaces must be escaped.

Comment: @Gala: but if you put the path between quotes, it does not have to be escaped. You can use `'C:\the file.mp3'` (with single quotes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows path in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: @Gala. But how *exactly* are you invoking this command? Show some actual code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To handle this problem I strongly suggest using

```
os.path.normpath('C:/Users/Thinkpad/Downloads/test file.srt')
```

If you enter all of your filename strings using forward slashes, and then let `os.path.normpath(path)` change them to backslashes for you, this way.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is anything in the standard library to handle this, but if it is just slashes and spaces you need a simple string replace will be faster and simpler. i.e.

```
path = path.replace('/','\\').replace(' ','\ ')
```